# Linux - Change permissions of all files & directories except 1 directory?

Tags: linux, directory, file-permissions, chmod

This has stumped me for a bit now after working on it for a while. I need to change the permission settings of all files and directories so that group and others have no read, write, or execute access except for one specific directory. So far I have tried variations of `

```
chmod go-rwx | chmod go+rwx 'filename'
```

Any tips?`

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a solution shorter than a 2 steps pipeline.

Otherwise, you might want to check umask.
umask changes the default permissions on a file on creation (sadly only on file created by the same shell, but you can add this to the .bash_rc/.bash_profile, so that every shell you'll open will do this by default)

```
umask 077
```

will set the mask so that every new file will have permissions like 700.
So you might want to just use this so that in the future you won't need to re-launch that pipeline.

EDIT
if the problem was the pipeline itself, then I'd do

```
cd && chmod -R 700 && cd 'path/to/that/directory' && chmod -R 777
```

with the double '&' instead of the pipe just because there's not output to pipe, so an && might do the trick

Comment: It's my last homework question and apparently it can be done in 1 line because the only requirement is that it be done in 1. Would I be able to use 'find' and pipe it to chmod?

Comment: chmod -R 'file' does it recursively! might help

Comment: @flarp: Yes, `find` is designed to pass the filenames it finds to another program.  You can `print` them, but in your case you would want to use `-exec` to build a command-line calling `chmod`.  And `find` has options to exclude certain patterns as well.

Comment: So would it look something like this?
    find -r | chmod go-rwx -exec 'filename'

Comment: maybe something like this then

     
    find / ! -name 'file' -exec chmod 700 {} \;